# Equivalent of "element.scrollHeight" for "window" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What's the equivalent to [`element.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight) for `window` in plain vanilla Javascript? I'm trying to rewrite code to target `window` or `document` instead of the `element`?

**Converting this:**
`remaining = element.scrollHeight - (element.clientHeight + element.scrollTop);`

**Into this:**
`remaining = window.scrollHeight - (window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset);`

Comment: `window.scrollMaxY`? (at least for Firefox)

Comment: Yup, it works on Firefox but not Chrome. Is there a cross-browser property?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight
```