# How to set a scrollTop after a display = block

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, scrolltop

I'm implementing a JavaScript function that does

```
document.getElementById("NTTable").style.display = "block"
```

(that's done) and will have that element (or element somewhere near it) will be in the center of the screen. When the JavaScript function runs the screen immediately goes to the top.

I have tried various offset and scrollTop but nothing. Where can I go from here?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742070/equivalent-of-element-scrollheight-for-window-in-javascript

Comment: Please, provide more information. Post your html/css code or examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery `show` and its callback function:

```
$("#NTTable").show(0,function(){ //0 is to simulate display="block" immediatley
  //your codes to scrolltop comes here
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Ali. I've got it now.